# Simple console program but I need GoF pattern for search algortihm

Tags: java, search, design-patterns

I am wondering what GoF pattern to look into in case of implementing a search function in my simple Java console program.

It is basically just a registry class that has the information of all the other model classes that have been registered.
I would then like to implement a search that returns members, registered, based on the search keywords used
i.e. keywords:  Enter name, phone number, car type, age.

I had imagined it to be like you enter the keywords you would like to search by and they would be searched as AND linking them together. Then you could get a new line to enter the keywords you would like and then those would be internally AND but linked to the former with OR.

Example(just x if you do not use keyword):

```
Name: John Phone-Number:x Car-Type: Wagon Age: >55
```

Would return a all Johns fullfilling the other keywords but:

```
Name: John Phone-Number:x Car-Type: x Age:x
Name: x Phone-Number:x Car-Type: Wagon Age: x
Name: x Phone-Number:x Car-Type: x Age: >55
```

Would return all Johns all owners of Wagons and all over 55

The UI is not the question/problem its just for explantation - the question is what GoF pattern should I look into for this implementation, I have been reading on them and I am not quite sure. Iterator patter maybe?

Comment: Visitor Design pattern can be used.

Comment: Why do you think you need a design pattern? Code doesn't require patterns.